# Update the Map data of an Array inside Firestore - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I've been trying to create a demo "Schedule-App" powered by Google's Firebase, but I'm facing some difficulties updating specific values of an **Array with Map values** on the side of Firestore.

As you can see on the following image, *what we want to achieve* is `onButtonPress`, this specific value to be updated.

[image]

I've created a Stream of data and manage it via `StreamProvider`.

```
StreamProvider<DocumentSnapshot>.value(
        value: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('schedule').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).snapshots(),
```

I'm using the following method to update Array's data, but it doesn't work.

```
  Future<void> updateUserData(int index, String title, String text, int hour, bool check) async {
    DocumentReference snapshots = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('schedule').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid);
    snapshots.update({
      ['standard_schedule'][index]: {'title': title, 'text': text, 'hour': hour, 'check': check}
    });
  }
```

What changes should I make to the method above, so that the bool value to be updated, every time the button is pressed?

===============================================

SOLUTION (10/24/2020):
Firestore **does not provide a way to update an array element at an index.** You have to read the entire document, modify the array in memory, then write the **entire array back to the document.**

Comment: Firestore does not provide a way to update an array element at an index.  You have to read the entire document, modify the array in memory, then write the entire array back to the document.

Comment: As it seems, this still is the case. All the related answers and articles I've read were at least 6 months old and I wasn't sure if this is still the case. Anyway, thank you for your reply.

Comment: Hi I've come across issue I'm trying to slove it but I've had stucked ,I'm using arrayRemove n ArrayUnion but not working ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore **does not provide a way to update an array element at an index**. You have to read the entire document, modify the array in memory, then write the **entire array back to the document**.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

```
var array=[{'title': title, 'text': text, 'hour': hour, 'check': check}];
snapshots.update({'standard_schedule': FieldValue.arrayUnion(scores)});
```