# Firestore addSnapshotListener with list/array in Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, radio-button

I am trying to use `addSnapshotListener` to listen to the changes of `radiobutton` in Firestore. Currently, I have:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- userid
            |
            ---Would you like to participate: yes
```

I want to store the response within another field in Firestore, similar to [this example](https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/04/04/using-cloud-firestore-in-flutter/) where I want to achieve the following structure in Firestore (i.e., `Agreement` should be expandable and store `Would you like to participate: yes`):

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- userid
            |
            ---Agreement:
                    Would you like to participate: yes
```

Below is the code I am working with for two `radiobutton`

Global:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference uidRef = db.collection("users").document(uid);
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton yesButton;
RadioButton noButton;
```

For the `OnCreate`,

```
        yesButton = findViewById(R.id.a1);
        noButton = findViewById(R.id.a2);
        radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        String yes = yesButton.getText().toString();
        String no = yesButton.getText().toString();
```

`addSnapshotListener` to listen the changes

```
   uidRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                            if (e != null) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                                return;
                            }
    
                        if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
                            String participate = snapshot.getString("Would you like to participate");
                            if (participate != null) {
                                    yesButton.setChecked(true);
                                } else {
                                    noButton.setChecked(true);
                                }
                            }
                        }
        });
```

The two radio buttons:

```
 yesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (yesButton.isChecked()) {
                            Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
                            update.put("Would you like to participate", yes);
                            uidRef.update(update).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response updated ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });

        noButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (noButton.isChecked()) {
                            Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
                            update.put("Would you like to participate", no);
                            uidRef.update(update).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response updated ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I tried with `Arrays.asList` on `update.put("Would you like to participate", Arrays.asList(yes));`, it will make the structure in Firestore but still does not achieve my goal:

```
"Would you like to participate":
   0: Yes
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by a list. Do you want to create a radio button for each element that exists in the `Agreement` array?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the response! I tried to clarify it and edited my question. Maybe I used wrong terminology. I simply would like to put the radio button responses under the array called `Agreement` to organize the data. `Agreement` is not shown to the user. Hope that its more clear and I appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding what the problem is with the shared code.

Comment: Sorry Alex for the confusion. I'd like to store the radio button response under the `Agreement` array, as indicated in the expected Firestore structure. Currently I can only map one string `Would you like to participate: Yes`. But I want to get the response under `Agreement` array to organize the data

Comment: I'm sorry but really cannot understand. Maybe you can provide a concrete (visual) example.

Comment: Sorry Alex for the confusion due to my unfamiliar terminology. I simply want to create something like the address, city, street in this example for my app: https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/04/04/using-cloud-firestore-in-flutter/ where address will be my `Agreement` and city is `Would you like to participate` and address is the radio button response`Yes` or `No`. In other words, putting the radio button within another field? I am having hard time to achieve this goal

Comment: I'm sorry but at least I tried. Maybe someone else will understand this.

Comment: :( sorry Alex. Could I try to revise and update the question with what the problem I am having?

Comment: Yes, you should give it a try.

Comment: I tried Alex and I hope it's a bit more clear in terms of the goal:)...

Comment: So you need two radio buttons for each question with the two options for yes and no?

Comment: Hi Alex. For this question I need two radio buttons for yes and no. I have other survey questions that have four and six options. Would I need to use constructor? Sorry I am self learning this topic.

Comment: Sorry Alex. Just wondering if the updated questions make more sense?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't.

Comment: I think its "Updating the Map data of an Array", identical to this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64447616/update-the-map-data-of-an-array-inside-firestore-flutter But I think its not possible then...?

Comment: That's definitely possible. Check this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073).

Comment: Thanks Alex! Would you be able to give me a hand on the current code if I want to achieve updating the map data of an array for my radio buttons?

Comment: Have you tried something in the code, as it is explained in the above resource?